# Procedure to devise Questionnaire

Tags: regression, correlation

I understand that the reliability and validity are key while constructing a questionnaire. Kindly advise if the following procedures are appropriate to devise a questionnaire:

1. After creating all the items in the questionnaire, I plan to test the question with a sample of 25 participants. Next, I will re-test the same questionnaire with the same sample group, at some other time. To check internal consistencies, I will run a regression analysis to find the value of Cronbach alpha or Rho.

Please advise.

Comment: Chronbach's alpha is not part of regression analysis.

Answer (score 1):

These procedures aren't bad, but they don't say anything about validity and don't fully address reliability.

Your first sentence "after creating all the items" covers a lot of ground. How will you write the items? How will you review them? How will you revise them?

"I plan to test the the question" what about pilot testing?

Testing and re-testing on a group is good, that gives you test-retest reliability. What will you do if it is low? How low is too low?

Chronbach alpha is a measure of internal consistency, that's also good. But, again, what is too low? What will you do if alpha is low? What about item analysis?

And what about validity? What constructs, tests, measures etc will you compare your results to? How will you be sure that your questions cover all the areas you want to cover? Will you do a factor analysis to see if there is evidence of multiple factors?

How extensive your questionnaire development should be depends partly on your budget and partly on what you intend to do with the questionnaire, but getting a fully validated questionnaire is a long and complex process.

Comment: You are correct. I meant a "pilot" testing with 25 participants for the testing and re-testing method. (i) I understand that if Cronbach alpha is closer to 1, does that indicate that the internal consistencies are strong among the items.

Comment: (ii) If alpha is low, I will delete/change the item that has low alpha. (iii) I am not sure how to perform item analysis. Kindly clarify.  (iv) So do I need to conduct a factor analysis as well in order to ensure that the constructs or measures are valid. The items of this questionnaire have been derived from existing validated questionnaire.

Comment: Item analysis involves looking at each item and seeing if it has good properties. E.g. if everyone gives the same answer, it isn't a useful item.

Comment: If you are deriving the items from an existing questionnaire, why not just use that one?

Comment: The context is different. For instance, the existing questionnaire has been used to evaluate perception of usability in the computer desktop domain, while my study is in the tablet area. That is why I needed to change the wording and at times, shorten the sentence etc.

Comment: Regarding Item Analysis, say if everyone says "disagree" on the 5 Likert Scale, does this become a red flag?

Comment: I do not understand what is meant by unidimensional scale? The link http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/faq/alpha.html explains that the eigen value of item1 is much larger than item2, and item1 accounts for 67% of the variance. Can you please elaborate what does that imply? Thank you

Comment: good answer. but I believe there are textbooks written on this topic. there is no way to possibly address all the issues in a post.

Comment: Does the order of the items in a questionnaire matter?

Comment: The order certainly can matter